# Execute as console application when parameter is set

Tags: c#, winforms

a few days ago, I developed a WinForms application in C# using VC#2010 Express. After creating and saving the project, I made it a console application in the project settings, so additional to the start form, a windows command line pops up. I used the console to output debug information (simply with the Console.Write() function).

So now, my app is ready for a release. I do not want the user to see the console, for sure, but I'd like to integrate a way to show the console to interested persons. So, the best way is an argument, I think (like -console), but I dont know how to start the program as a console application only when an argument is set. I know how to handle the args[] array, for sure, but I have no idea how to show the console when there is an arg. I already tried it by simply starting the program via command line(CMD -> prog.exe), but it did not work. The program starts, but the console directly shows the current path after starting the program, as usual.

Is there any possibility for my intention?

Comment: I'd say you're better off logging to a log file, is that a feasible approach ? use e.g. `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` instead of Console.WriteLine and you can easily configure that output to end in a log file, or with about 30 lines of code, hook up your own trace listener and output the information in a winforms window (that can be hidden/shown with a hotkey)

Comment: Pinvoke AllocConsole() when you see the command line argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link to kernel32.dll and use the function `AttachConsole`.
Here's an example: http://www.csharp411.com/console-output-from-winforms-application/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no way to have a single binary support both console and non-console behaviour, with the choice being made on start-up. All the work-arounds I've seen use two binaries.

There's a discussion [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch20.html) on how Python deals with the problem (boldface mine):

> **The standard Python.exe** that comes with Python **is known as a console application** (this means it has been built to interact with a Windows console, otherwise known as a DOS box or command prompt). Although you can execute your Tkinter programs using Python.exe, **your program will always be associated with a Windows console**. It works just fine, but has the following side effects:
>
> - If you execute Python.exe from Windows Explorer, a new empty console window is created; then the Tkinter windows are created.
> - If you execute a Tkinter application under Python.exe from a command prompt, the command prompt doesn't return until the Tkinter application has finished. This will be a surprise for many users, who expect that executing a GUI program returns the command prompt immediately.
>
> To get around this problem, **Python comes with a special GUI version called Pythonw.exe**. This is almost identical to the standard Python.exe, except it's not a console program, so doesn't suffer the problems described previously.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the command line arguments for the Winform in the forms load event and then if the argument is for the console, open the console.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    foreach(string arg in args)
    {
       if(arg == "consoleargument")
       {
           // Run console
       }
    }
}
```